# How programmatically push segue in Storyboard?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, segue

[image]

How to push view controller programmatically? In some case not button press but programmatic trigger needs. How?

Need write something like:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"menu41" sender:self];
```

or

```
[self.self.navigationController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"menu41" sender:self];
```

Added an identifier "menu41" to segue.

Comment: Why would not use [self.navigationController pushViewController...]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:
use this code to perform segue:

> self.performSegueWithIdentifier("menu41", sender: self)

This will call method where you can pass values or perform any specific activity as per requirement.

> override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender:
>   AnyObject!) { if segue.identifier == "menu41" {
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

You should use   `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"menu41" sender:self];`

See the Discussion section on [Apple Dev forum](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621413-performsegue)